# Haproxy agent-check

Tags: mysql, haproxy

I am following the guides to setup haproxy for mysql load balancer, and to detect slave lag and change weight accordingly.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/18/making-haproxy-1-5-replication-lag-aware-in-mysql/#comment-10967915

I manage to setup the PHP file (run as service) and it listen well to the port defined (3307). Telnet to the port 3307 is a success and it return the correct *seconds_behind_master* value.

**Now the Haproxy part:**

After configuring Haproxy and reload, the Haproxy doesn't do any agent-check on the port 3307.
I shut down the slave to make the seconds_behind_master = *NULL*, check the haproxy web interface, nothing is changed. The slave server is still up and running.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Tried using both haproxy 1.5.19 (upgrade from previous version) and 1.6.3 (fresh install)

Update:

```
Haproxy configuration
    frontend read_only-front
            bind *:3310
            mode tcp
            option tcplog
            log global
    default_backend read_only-back
            backend read_only-back
            mode tcp
            balance leastconn
            server db01 1.1.1.1:3306 weight 100 check agent-check agent-port 6789 inter 1000  rise 1 fall 1 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
            server db02 2.2.2.2:3306 weight 100 check agent-check agent-port 6789 inter 1000  rise 1 fall 1 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
```

Mange to Telnet and "fputs" the weight in PHP script, when I Stop Slave of 1 of the mysql server.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 6789
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
down
```

However, when checking the stats, it still shows 100 up. I even try other variable such as "up 1%", still unable to change the weight.

```
echo "show stat" | socat stdio /run/haproxy/admin.sock | cut -d ',' -f1,2,18,19
# pxname,svname,status,weight
read_only-front,FRONTEND,OPEN,
read_only-back,db-vu01,UP,100
read_only-back,db-vu02,UP,100
read_only-back,BACKEND,UP,200
```

Comment: Please include your config and script.

Comment: @TanHongTat Please check the codes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the `agent-addr` or `addr` = 1.1.1.1:6789 and 2.2.2.2:6789 ?

Comment: @TanHongTat agent is at localhost (127.0.0.1:6789)
1.1.1.1:3306 and 2.2.2.2:3306 is the sample mysql server IP address.

Comment: The agent should be on the mysql server; 1.1.1.1:6789 and 2.2.2.2:6789, not in the server that runs HAProxy.

Comment: @TanHongTat tried to run agent in mysql server with port 6789, not working as well. Actually how do Haproxy write weight? Is there any command line I can do it directly? Maybe I should start from some simple example.

Comment: I suspect haproxy not even talking to agent?

Comment: I tried to run the command "mysql -Ee "show slave status" | grep Seconds_Behind_Master", the php agent doesn't not return any echo value I put there eg "up 50%". Meaning, the haproxy is not connecting to PHP agent at all.